# Bounded Iterator - limit and offset

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using this [BoundedIterator](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-spi-commons/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/spi/commons/iterator/BoundedIterator.java) as an internal iterator in one of my app.

Using it to make a existing `Iterator` bounded:

```
public DBCursor limit(Integer limit){
    this.max = limit;
    this._it = new BoundedIterator<DBObject>(this.offset, this.max, this._it);
    return this;
}

public DBCursor skip(Integer skip){
    this.offset = skip;
    this._it = new BoundedIterator<DBObject>(this.offset, this.max, this._it);
    return this;
}
```

This works fine:

```
DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(it).limit(5).skip(1);
```

This pieceof code is able to skip 1 item on the orignal Iterator, then limit the result to 5.

See:

```
{"_id":"51a6dc852318dcd7f1e1c09f","number":2}
{"_id":"51a6dc852318dcd7f1e1c0a0","number":3}
{"_id":"51a6dc852318dcd7f1e1c0a1","number":4}
{"_id":"51a6dc852318dcd7f1e1c0a2","number":5}
```

Where the first element was skipped and the last element is 5.

Now the problem is when this is done:

```
DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(it).skip(5).limit(1);
```

This returns empty result.

My expected result would be that it will skip 5 element and limit the result to 1.

I think this is a problem with the way `BoundedIterator` do skip and limit on the element:

**BoundedIterator.java**

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next == null) {
            fetchNext();
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    public T next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return consumeNext();
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private void fetchNext() {
        for (; pos < offset && iterator.hasNext(); pos++) {
            next = iterator.next();
        }
        if (pos < offset || !iterator.hasNext() || max >= 0 && pos - offset + 1 > max) {
            next = null;
        }
        else {
            next = iterator.next();
            pos++;
        }
    }

    private T consumeNext() {
        T element = next;
        next = null;
        return element;
    }
```

What should be improved on this code. Is it with the BoundIterator's code that needs to be altered or just in my app's skip and limit methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BoundedEditor.java change pos - offset + 1 > max to pos - offset + 1 >= max

Comment: That change caused unit tests in my app to fail... I mean that used to work